# Form flickers when updating with meteor-autoform

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using

```
{{> quickForm collection="Meteor.users" id="updateUserForm" type="update" doc=this fields="profile.firstName,profile.lastName,profile.birthday,profile.gender,profile.bio"}}
```

to update my user profile.

But when submitting the form, the page 'rerenders' and shows the updated form. Without using `meteor-autoform`, I am able to create form input fields and update the database with click on submit button. But with `meteor-autoform`, the page flickers after updating the database. Can I avoid this flickering/rerender/redrawing?